# NewtonSoft Json Invalid Cast Exception

Tags: c#, json, json.net

This is related to my question [HTTPClient Buffer Exceeded 2G; Cannot write more bytes to the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39421553/httpclient-buffer-exceeded-2g-cannot-write-more-bytes-to-the-buffer) but is different enough that IMO it warrants a separate question.

In the other question, I'm trying to figure out how to deal with breaking the 2G request buffer. The idea was to use streaming, but I need to deserialize. In talking to Professor Google, I found that I have to use TextReader to stream/deserialize. so my code for that is:

```
    public async Task<API_Json_Special_Feeds.RootObject> walMart_Special_Feed_Lookup(string url)
    {
        special_Feed_Lookup_Working = true;
        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate
        };
        using (HttpClient http = new HttpClient(handler))
        {

            http.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.StringWithQualityHeaderValue("gzip"));
            http.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Timeout.Infinite);
            url = String.Format(url);
            using (var response = await http.GetAsync(url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(response);
                var serializer = new JsonSerializer();

                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()))
                {
                    using (var jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
                    {
                        API_Json_Special_Feeds.RootObject root = (API_Json_Special_Feeds.RootObject)serializer.Deserialize(jsonTextReader);
                        return root;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, as you can see, the return type is strongly typed. The return type of the method matches. Now, I go to the calling line:

```
  API_Json_Special_Feeds.RootObject Items = await net.walMart_Special_Feed_Lookup(specialFeedsURLs[i].Replace("{apiKey}", Properties.Resources.API_Key_Walmart));
```

So, we have matching types API_Json_Special_Feeds.RootMethod all the way around.

When run, the calling line throws an InvalidCastException:

**Undesired Result:**

```
Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to type 'RootObject'
```

I've checked at the end of the method before return, and the result is indeed cast from an object to API_Json_Special_Feeds.RootMethod before being returned.

**Question:** somewhere between the return statement and the calling line, the object being returned is being converted from an API_Json_Special_Feeds.RootMethod to a Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject. I can't debug it since there's no code in between. If I cast again in the calling line, I get a "Cannot cast" error. How can I prevent the degradation/changing of this object type?

Many, many thinks for your time, consideration, and for any thoughts or suggestions you can provide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the generic overload [`JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_Deserialize__1.htm)

```
var root = serializer.Deserialize<API_Json_Special_Feeds.RootObject>(jsonTextReader);
```

Unlike files generated by `BinaryFormatter`, JSON files generally do not include c# type information, so it's necessary for the receiving system to specify the expected type.

(There are extensions to the [JSON standard](http://www.json.org/) in which c# type information can be included in a JSON file -- e.g. Json.NET's [`TypeNameHandling`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializetypenamehandling.htm) -- but it is still necessary to deserialize the JSON to an appropriate explicit base class.)

See [Deserialize JSON from a file](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeWithJsonSerializerFromFile.htm) for another example of deserializing a strongly typed c# object from a stream.

Comment: Thank you! So far, that's not working. I'm trying to figure out where it's stuck and will report back. No error - loads response and never returns anything