# Web API 2 upload large json strings

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm after some advice on what the best strategy is for posting a large object from a client to a web api post method on the server? Is there a standard strategy that is followed? My class that I'm posting to the server is as follows:-

```
public class DataSetValidationRequest
{
   public string DataSetName { get; set; }
   public string JsonString { get; set; }
}
```

The JsonString property essentially holds a serialized DataTable which can contain ~200,000 rows (when this string is saved down to disk, it amounts to ~30mb)

I'm currently using the deflate algorithm to compress the DataSetValidationRequest object down before I send it to the server and then I decompress the compressed stream on the server back into the original stream. I then use JsonConvert to parse the stream back into the request object but I get OutOfMemoryExceptions. Is there a better way to do this in chunks somehow? I thought about splitting the data up into multiple chunks and making multiple requests to the server but then I would need to implement some form of transaction control to ensure that all the data is successfully transferred across the wire and it just doesn't seem like a great idea!

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I asked a similar question in reverse a while back. Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39421553/httpclient-buffer-exceeded-2g-cannot-write-more-bytes-to-the-buffer - I was able to use the stream to deserialize (in your case, serialize) one object at a time (through the same constant stream) -- Good luck!

Comment: Hi Shannon, I didn't see how you did that in your post. Have you got an example? Do you mean that I'd be able use my stream to deserialize? I've tried that with JsonConvert but it doesn't work - I think it just reads the whole string into memory and then tries to serialize.

Comment: It does - normally. The answers provided me on that question allowed me to deserialize one at a time (the same can be applied to serialization). I'm sorry - I no longer have the working example, but the answer is in the answers I received.